# c# moving files between different directories

Tags: c#

This is my entire code, it reads in csv files and outputs certain numbers and then moves the file to another folder. The thing I need help fixing is the way it pulls in the files and the way it moves them. I currently have two folders named Hotels and Completed Hotels. Inside the Hotels folder it has subfolders for each of the 6 different hotels. The way it works now, it will pull all of the files at once from the entire Hotels folder, from each hotel folder and move them all into the completed hotels folder. What I want to change is to have a completed folder inside of each individual hotel folder and I want it to pull the data from a hotel and put it in its own completed folder, and then move onto the next hotel and do the same thing, how would I change my code to implement this?

Code below:

```
class ManagerReport
{
    static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string originalPath, string destinationPath)
    {
        // first check if path exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(originalPath))
            // doesn't exist then exit, can't copy from something that doesn't exist
            return;
        var copyPathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(originalPath);
        // using the SearchOption.AllDirectories will search sub directories
        var copyPathCSVFiles = copyPathDirectory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // loops through directory looking for txt files
        for (var i = 0; i < copyPathCSVFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            // get the file
            var csvFile = copyPathCSVFiles[i];

            // [...] parse and import the file

            // creates a variable that combines the the directory of the new folder with the file name
            var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, csvFile.Name);
            // This loop prevents duplicates. If a file is already in the folder, it will delete the file already in there and move this one in.
            // Shouldn't be an issue since each file will have a different name
            if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
            {
                File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
            }
            // moves it to the new folder
            csvFile.MoveTo(destinationFilePath);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessFilesCSVFiles(@"C:\Users\Documents\Hotels", @"C:\Users\Documents\Completed Hotels");
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Can you read [ask] and provide a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**?

Comment: I'm not sure where to even begin because I feel like the way it is written now won't work at all. Right now it is pulling all txt files it sees but my issue is that i'm worried it will pull the txt files from the completed folders as well

Comment: what happened to the rest of the code you had posted.. also personally I think that you could have done this a lot easier by create a Class that mimics the structure of the csv file that you are trying to read from and or create, then use auto properties for the csv fields, then create a List<ManagerReportNames> class.. and read the lines into the class then save the data as csv etc...

Comment: @MethodMan that was CSV parsing and database updating code which was not relevant to the question at all, so I edited it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially, you have a source file structure like this:

```
Prefix\Hotel1\File1.csv
Prefix\Hotel1\File2.csv
Prefix\Hotel2\File1.csv
Prefix\Hotel3\File3.csv
```

Which you want to process and then move to the destination directories like this:

```
Prefix\Hotel1\Completed\File1.csv
Prefix\Hotel1\Completed\File2.csv
Prefix\Hotel2\Completed\File1.csv
Prefix\Hotel3\Completed\File3.csv
```

Your current code uses `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, which recursively scans the directories and returns the full paths. To determine which file belongs to which folder, you'll need to split the path again and determine the parent folder.

A trivial fix would be to simply iterate over the source directories, processing and moving files as you go:

```
foreach (var hotelDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory))
{
    foreach (var inputFile in Directory.GetFiles(hotelDirectory))
    {
        // process inputFile

        var destinationPath = Path.Combine(hotelDirectory, "Completed");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

        var destinationFileName = Path.GetFileName(inputFile);
        destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationFileName);

        File.Move(inputFile, destinationPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you. The only issue is that I'm getting this error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Documents\Hotels\HEW\HEW.txt'.

Comment: This error is happening at the File.Move part. When i checked my folder, the file has been moved already

Comment: Yeah, so you must have left over some of your code.

Comment: I removed the entire bottom part which I had originally used to move the files. I left the top part but why would the file have already moved than?

Comment: The code I posted moves the file once. If it's already moved, there's other code I can't help with. Set breakpoints, step through your code.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you